# What happens with Synology Drive backup tasks that are scheduled at a time where the computer is down?

Tags: backup, nas, synology, synology-diskstation

I am using the Synology Drive Backup tasks, and I would like to switch to a daily backup instead of a continuous backup, in order to avoid constant network traffic when working on large files.

But what happens when the computer is turned off at the scheduled backup time is not clear. I checked the option "Continue any uncompleted tasks when the system is in operation again", and to test it out I defined a new task, set the backup time at 04am (when my computer is always off), and updated some files. I thought the task would be triggered when the computer woke up in the morning, but it didn't... Nothing happened. It seems that the wording of the option is to be taken literally: an **uncompleted** task when the computer shuts down or goes to sleep resumes when the computer wakes up, but if the task didn't start at all at the scheduled time it won't start later. It looks poorly designed...

Then I left all of this untouched, and then 48 hours after updating the files, the backup task triggered in the middle of the day (even though the computer had been turned on since the morning).

I don't quite understand the logic of how it works? And the Synology knowledge base doesn't really help.

EDIT: [image]

Comment: You need to show us the definition of this scheduled task.